# AccountManager adds account but does not show up under Accounts in Settings

Tags: android

I have created a custom account type by following the SimpleSyncAdapter example provided by android. I am able to add accounts with the Account Manager, and on some phones (tested on Galaxy S3, Galaxy Nexus, HTC Desire HD), I do see my account under Accounts and Sync in Settings. To add an account, I am doing the following:

```
boolean added = mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, null);
```

However, on the Galaxy Note 2 and the Motorola Xoom, even though this returns true, the account does not appear under Accounts and Sync.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Is there a warning on LogCat? 

Try to install the sample app from this post on your problematic device:
http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the setAccountAuthenticatorResult call.

```
boolean added = mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, new Bundle());
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, username);
intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
setAccountAuthenticatorResult(intent.getExtras());
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this question because I was having the same problem on the emulator. I could access the Account details through the AccountManager, but it didn't show up in Accounts & Sync. I finally restarted the emulator with 'Wipe user data' checked, and the problem went away.

I don't know how to mimic that process on your devices, but perhaps deleting said Account using AccountManager.removeAccount(...) will clear some legacy account data and allow you to reset the Account. There is clearly a disconnect between the Account data, the AccountManager and SyncAdapter configuration, and the availability of the Account in Accounts & Sync. I just don't understand where it is.

I hope this helps a more knowledgeable contributor to answer the original question more completely.